# How to replace the stiffness matrix in ANSYS Mechanical APDL?

Tags: ansys, ansys-apdl

It is necessary to perform a calculation for a one-dimensional problem with a jump (this is some constant given in the displacements). There is a rod with areas V1 and V2, a border between them. At the border, the nodes are double numbered. There are two ways, the first is to register a contact condition at the border in ANSYS, but I do not know how to do this. (I will be glad if someone tells me.) I know that the contact condition has the form:

ui (on the left border) = ui (on the right border) - Ui, where Ui is a jump in movements, which is given by the condition of the problem.

Since I did not find a way to prescribe a contact condition in ANSYS, a method was chosen to extract the global stiffness matrix from ANSYS, modify it and load it back.

I got the global stiffness matrix from ANSYS Mechanical APDL using the following two commands:
*DMAT, MatKD, D, IMPORT, FULL, file.full, STIFF
*PRINT, MatKD, Kdense.matrix

Then I edited it and want to upload it back. What commands should I use for this?

There is also another question: how to get the load vector F from ANSYS? (Which is used together with the stiffness matrix A*U=F.)

Thank you in advance. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can you explain why you could not find a contact condition in ANSYS? Are you looking for specific kind of contact? Here is an example on contact creation in [ANSYS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9dYcIkg3Z4)